# Why are win numbers not counted correct?

Tags: php

I have a script which generates random numbers. From this generated list of random numbers the script creates win numbers. Win numbers are just simply counts when a number wins and a number wins when there is a duplicate. It does this now but it starts counting after each win but it must start counting at the win number. Is this more clear? This is a script to create a system in roulette so it only needs to count until a win everytime.

```
<?php

$existing = [];
$win_numbers = [];

for ($rnd = 1; $rnd <= 80; $rnd++) {
$randoms[] = mt_rand(0, 36);
}

echo "Random Number:<br>";
echo implode('-', $randoms).PHP_EOL;

echo "<br><br>";

$i = 1;
foreach ($randoms as $rnd) {
if (in_array($rnd, $existing)) {
    $win_numbers[] = $i;
    $i = 1;
    $existing = [];
} else {
    $existing[] = $rnd;
    $i++;
}
}

echo "Win Numbers:<br>";
echo implode('-', $win_numbers);

?>
```

I hope this helps more in explaining what I mean. I have explained it thoroughly this time.

Comment: I do not understand what do you want to achieve here, can you edit your post and explain?

Comment: I have edited and made it more clear. Please run the script to see what I mean.

Comment: Your edit made it actually less clear, you removed some explanation. Your expected result seems off to me, If you start counting from 1 from the next number after the match, your match positions should be 8 and 8. You should precise what is the result that the code currently gives, we shouldn't be forced to create a script from your code to know that

Comment: You are right. The first match is correct which is 8. But then we should start the new counting at 8 and then the next match is 9. But it doesn't do this. It gives as match als 8 because it doesn't count the first number.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the logic behind this. In your sample '4' and '7' also appear more than once. Why don't you count them as matches?

Comment: It's how I need it unfortunatly. Can you help me?

Comment: No, we can not help you, as long as you can not properly explain the _logic_ behind this - and just saying _“it's how I need it unfortunatly”_  does not do that, explain the actual logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching numbers are not working correct and I need average numbers too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57030833/matching-numbers-are-not-working-correct-and-i-need-average-numbers-too)

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of the same question you asked not only half a day earlier to begin with. Please refrain from creating such duplicates - edit the original question, if you have more info / clarification to add, and then show some _patience_.

Comment: Oké, let me say it like this. I am creating a roulette script where I can test certain systems. A match is basically a win. And that's why I don't count all duplicates. Does this make more clear? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I've tried to understand this question and have given up.  Try and explain what you are trying to achieve first.  I'd delete this and your previous similar question, and start again.  Give expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: I changed the description inside the original request. I hope this helps now.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
for ($rnd = 1; $rnd <= 80; $rnd++) {
$randoms[] = mt_rand(0, 100);
}
```

to this

```
for ($rnd = 1; $rnd <= 20; $rnd++) {
$randoms[] = "".mt_rand(0, 100);
}
```

Comment: The first match number is correct but the following ones are 1 to long so the 8 should be a 7.